# How to iterate multiple String input in Java using the Scanner class

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I need to get multiple line Input from a User in Java.
Currently I'm using the Scanner class to get the input, but the loop I'm using
to check each line does not break.

**Current Code**

```
package getxml;

import java.util.Scanner;


public class Test{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
          
    System.out.println("Enter the Codes: ");   
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    
    while(in.hasNextLine()) {
        String nextLine = in.nextLine();
        System.out.println("nextLine:" + nextLine);
    }   
    in.close();
    System.out.println("Scanner closed");
    }
}
```

**Expected Input**

```
10229892
10120470
10295277
10229618
10229643
10229699
```

**Expected Output**

```
nextLine:10229892
nextLine:10120470
nextLine:10295277
nextLine:10229618
nextLine:10229643
nextLine:10229699
Scanner closed
```

**Real Output**

```
nextLine:10229892
nextLine:10120470
nextLine:10295277
nextLine:10229618
nextLine:10229643
nextLine:10229699
```

I have tried changing the

```
hasNextLine()
```

to

```
hasNext()
```

And adding a If condition to break out of the loop with following logic:

```
if (nextLine.equals("")) {
    in.close();
    System.out.println("bye");
    break;
}
```

I **need** to secure the in.nextLine() to a variable, otherwise it will iterate 2 lines in one loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you will have to decide what is going to be considered **The End Of User Input** and then act upon that specific condition. In the little example below, if the User enters ***nothing*** then that will be considered the **End Of User Input**.

All the code numbers entered by the User are stored within a List Interface object. Rules have also been applied whereas all code numbers supplied **must** be **numerical** and **eight digits in length**. The [String#matches()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_matches.htm) method is used for this along with a small [Regular Expression](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html) (regex). Also, there can be no duplicate code numbers supplied, each code number must be **unique**.

When the User has finished entering the desired Code Numbers then those numbers are sorted in ascending order and displayed within the console window:

```
System.out.println("Enter the required code numbers (enter nothing when done): ");   
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

List<String> codes = new ArrayList<>();
// Outer loop to keep asking for Code Numbers
while (true) {
    boolean isValid = false; // Flag to ensure a valid entry
    String codeLine = "";
    // inner loop to back up valitity before storing supplied code Number.
    while (!isValid) {    
        System.out.print("Code Line: --> ");
        codeLine = in.nextLine().trim();
        // Break out of this inner loop if nothing is supplied
        if (codeLine.isEmpty()) { break; } 
        // Is the supplied number all digits and are there 8 of them? 
        if (!codeLine.matches("^\\d{8}$")) {
            // No...
            System.err.println("Invalid Code Number! Try Again...");
        }
        // Has the supplied number already been previously stored?
        // In other words, is it unique?
        else if (codes.contains(codeLine)) {
            // Already got it! Not Unique!
            System.err.println("Code Number: " + codeLine + " has already been supplied!");
        }
        // Passed validity! Set isValid to true so to exit this inner loop.
        else { isValid = true; }
    }
    // Break out of the outer loop is nothing was supplied.
    if (codeLine.isEmpty()) { break; }
        
    // Validity has been met so Store the the supplied code number.
    codes.add(codeLine);
}
in.close(); // Close the input Stream
System.out.println("Scanner closed");
    
// Sort the Stored Code Numbers in ascending order.
Collections.sort(codes);
    
// Display the Stored Code Numbers...
System.out.println("Code Numbers Entered:");
System.out.println(codes);
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that your code does not know if the user has stopped entering the codes.

You can do something like this :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println("Enter the Codes: ");

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    String nextLine = "";
    do{
        nextLine = in.nextLine();
        System.out.println("nextLine:" + nextLine);
    } while(!nextLine.equals("exit"));

    in.close();


    System.out.println("Scanner closed");
}
```

And you console will look like:

[image]

Comment: I'm trying to make java detect the "end of input" by itself, instead of coding a "end-word" in.

Comment: @Reachyy That's not working using `System.in`. It's a infinite source of input data and you dont know where is the end. You can change it by counter, endword, single-enter press, ... but `System.in` will always continue listening to the next input or bevaving like there is more.
In comparison: Reading a file from start to end you can use `hasNextLine()` and stop then. That's a limited source.

Comment: @LenglBoy I had a feeling that System.in might always be listening. Thank you for clarifying! +

Answer (score 0):

"Enter" is end of input. What you are trying to do is *simulate* or work around that. If your objective is to *just simulate* multiline input, following should work:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("Enter the Codes: ");   
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        String allLines = "";
        while(in.hasNextLine()) {
            String nextLine = in.nextLine().trim();
            if (nextLine.isEmpty() || nextLine.equals("\r") || nextLine.equals("\r\n") || nextLine.equals("\n")) {
                break;
            }
            allLines += "\r\n" + nextLine;
            //System.out.println("nextLine:" + nextLine);
        }
        System.out.println("all lines:" + allLines);
        in.close();
        
        System.out.println("Scanner closed");
}
```